# Painel login não retorna o numero de contas

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando uma área de login, porém quando eu clico no botão de login, não retorna nenhum erro, por exemplo: se o usuário não existir eu gostaria que aparecesse o número 0 conforme a variável `$num`, porém aparece uma tela em branco na página.

*PHP*:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname) or die(mysqli_error());


    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {

      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $senha = $_POST['senha'];

      $get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM  usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'");
      $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

          echo $num;
    }
?>
```

*HTML*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Painel Admin Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário"><br>
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bem provável que esteja caindo na condição: `if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {`. Aliás, cadê a chave fechando essa condição?!

Comment: não postei o códico inteiro hehe, mas tem a chave fechando a condição, sou iniciante, e não consegui entender bem oque tu disseste :/

Comment: Vou formular uma resposta. Daí vc vai comentando e eu vou editando a resposta até resolver seu problema. 1 instante.

Comment: Eu queria que, quando o usuario é inexistente, aparecesse a mensagem: Usuario ou Senha incorretos/Inexistente.

Comment: Oq tudo indica é que vc está tendo problemas pra passar os valores do seu formulário pra essa página. Tem como postar seu `form`?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Resposta atualizada. Agora tudo deve funcionar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> porém aparece uma tela em branco na página

Bem provável que esteja caindo nessa condição:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {
```

> sou iniciante, e não consegui entender bem oque tu disseste

O código espera que seja passado via `post` os valores de `email` e `senha`. Caso não, ele pula todo esse bloco, que aliás, falta o fechamento dessa condição (`}`).

A fim de teste, pode colocar uma contra-condição no seu código. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $senha = $_POST['senha'];

  $get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM  usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'");
  $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

      echo $num;

} else echo "e-Mail e/ou senha não informados!";
```

Dessa forma, sua página deve exibir a mensagem *caso não tenha passado os valores de `email` e `senha`*.

**@edit:**

Repare bem que no seu *HTML* tem estes `input`:

```
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário"><br>
<input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha"><br>
```

E no *script PHP* você está recebendo estas variáveis:

```
//...
// Aqui deveria ser "usuario" ao invés de "email"
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {
    //...
    $email = $_POST['email']; // Aqui deveria ser "usuario"
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    //...
```

Os atributos `name` do formulário devem ser compatíveis com as *chaves* buscadas na variável `$_POST`.

**@edit2:**

Finalmente, o código conclui-se assim:

*login.php:*

```
<?php
    if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) session_start();

        $dbInfo = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'usuario' => 'root',
        'senha' => '',
        'db' => 'login'
    );

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbInfo['host'], $dbInfo['usuario'], $dbInfo['senha'], $dbInfo['db']) or die(mysqli_error());

    if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && $_POST['usuario'] != '' && strlen($_POST['usuario']) >= 4 && isset($_POST['senha']) && $_POST['senha'] != '') {

        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];

        if(!($get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM  usuarios WHERE nome = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha';"))){
            echo "Erro na consulta: ".mysqli_error($conn);
            die(); // Para toda a execução do código.
        }
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
            echo "Login efetuado com sucesso!";
        } else {
            echo "Falha ao efetuar o login";
        }

    } else echo "Usuário e/ou senha não informados.";

    // Logout:
    //unset($_SESSION['logado']);

?>
```

*index.php:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Painel Admin Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="required" minlength="4"><br>
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Estrutura do banco de dados (MariaDB):*

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nome  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| senha | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| adm   | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Maninho, ok, deu certo, mas por mais que o login esteja certo, aparece a mensagem :/

Comment: Ok, corrigido, porem maninho, eu queria retornar a variável num, se o usuario é inexistente como está no código " echo $num", porém a pagina não aparece nada

Comment: Corrigi o código.

Answer (score 1):

Se no PHP é `isset($_POST['email']` então no HTML deve ser `<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">` que é o mais sugestivo.

Agora nada inpede de no HTML ser `<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário">` porém no PHP deve ser `isset($_POST['usuario']`

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","USUARIO","SENHA",Nome_DB");

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])) {

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $senha = $_POST['senha'];
  
  $get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM  usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'");
  $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

      echo $num;
}
 ?>
 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Painel Admin Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Pelo que se pode perceber, você não queria somente saber qual era o erro na sua pergunta, que havia sido dado em um comentário meu, já excluído. Vou lhe postar uma resposta completa e segura para que tenha um bom aprendizado.

**1 -** Seja criterioso ao construir sua instrução SELECT, pois quanto mais dados são lidos das tabelas, mais tempo levará sua execução. Especialmente quando o servidor de banco de dados estiver separado do servidor de aplicação, porque os dados vão ter que passar pela rede entre os dois.

Crie o hábito de sempre especificar as colunas de que vai precisar ao montar o seu SELECT.

**2 -**  `<input type="email">` valida o campo para garantir que o dado digitado seja de fato um endereço de e-mail válido.

**3 -**  `required` é um atributo booleano usado para indicar que um determinando campo de formulário é obrigatório para o envio do mesmo. Ao adicionar esse atributo a um campo de formulário, o navegador obriga o usuário a inserir dados naquele campo antes de enviar o formulário.

**4 -** Evite SQL Injection usando Prepared Statements no PHP.

Uma das maiores vulnerabilidades de sites, a injeção de SQL (SQL Injection) é também, no caso do PHP, uma das mais fáceis de prevenir. Infelizmente, muitos não tomam as devidas precauções e acabam tendo os seus dados comprometidos.

No exemplo vou usar `prepared statements` usando a extensão `PDO` do PHP

> No PHP, a extensão MySQLi também suporta statements preparados, mas é melhor utilizar o PDO pois ele facilita a migração para outros bancos, além de oferecer uma API concisa entre eles.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USUARIO";
$password = "SENHA";
$dbname = "Nome_DB";


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if ( (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) &&  (isset($_POST['senha']) && !empty($_POST['senha'])) ) {
    
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    
        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // define o modo de erro do PDO para exceção
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE email= :email and senha = :senha");
             $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
             $stmt->execute();
             
             $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             
             $count =  count($users);
        
                echo $count;    
        
        }

            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
        
        $conn = null;
    
    }else{
        echo "Os dois campos são obrigatorios";
    }

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Painel Admin Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required><br>
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**5 -** Porque validação do lado cliente (Front-end) e lado servidor (Back-end)?

Validar dados sendo enviados pelo usuário só no javascript não é o suficiente por causa de:

- se o usuário desativar o javascript, você pode acabar com dados inválidos no servidor
- Porque o front-end fica acessível no navegador. E todo o código que lá está, pode acabar sendo alterado por alguém que tenha um conhecimento avançado e más intenções. O código JavaScript pode perfeitamente ser alterado e assim a validação pode ser burlada.
- validações no servidor fazem um site menos suscetível a robôs maliciosos

Em resumo... vale a pena precaver contra todos esses agentes desconhecidos, fazendo a validação no servidor (que é o agente mais confiável) como sendo a principal... e no javascript, como sendo um agilizador de validação, por não necessitar de ir no servidor.

**6 -** - Bloco try/catch serve para tratamento de exceções, tratamento de códigos que podem não ser totalmente atendidos e gerarem alguma exceção/erro.

O try consegue recuperar erros que possam ocorrer no código fornecido em seu bloco.
O catch por sua vez faz o tratamento dos erros que aconteceram.

Deve ser utilizado preferencialmente quando o desenvolvedor não tem como garantir que o código será executado com sucesso.